Azure still using my old tenant ID for authentication
I had been using my Microsoft account for Azure and successfully authenticated using its credentials. I also created an Entra app in that account and set up permissions for it.
Recently, I created a new Azure account with a different email and set up a new Entra app there. I want to switch completely to this new Azure account.
In my Python app, I'm using the Azure SDK with DefaultCredentials() and have set the following environment variables to point to the new account:

AZURE_TENANT_ID
AZURE_CLIENT_ID
AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET

When I use the old account's credentials, everything works fine, and I'm able to upload blobs to my storage account. However, when I switch to the new account by updating the environment variables, Azure still tries to use the old AZURE_TENANT_ID, resulting in an authorization error:

azure.core.exceptions.ClientAuthenticationError: The current credential is not configured to acquire tokens for tenant {my_old_tenant_id}. To enable acquiring tokens for this tenant add it to the additionally_allowed_tenants when creating the credential, or add "*" to additionally_allowed_tenants to allow acquiring tokens for any tenant.

Tried:

Removing my old tenant_id from my code completely.
Removed ~/.azure folder.
Hardcoded my new tenant_id in the azure code.


"...when I switch to the new account by updating the environment variables ..." are you restarting the application/session/whatever after the variables are updated?

Yes @RuiJarimba. I am, still I'm facing the same problem.

@vishalpanchal, Try adding credential = DefaultAzureCredential(additionally_allowed_tenants=['*']) in your code.

The ClientAuthenticationError occurs if the requested tenant_id doesn’t match the tenant ID configured on the credential.
Run command az account show and check if the valid Tenant is active currently.

Add all the Tenant IDs from which the tokens should be acquired, to the additionally_allowed_tenants list in credential options  as mentioned  in the blog and MSDOC.
credential  =  DefaultAzureCredential(additionally_allowed_tenants=["*"])

(or)
credential = DefaultAzureCredential(additionally_allowed_tenants = ["<tenant_id_1>", "<tenant_id_2>"])

Sample Code:
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

account_url = "https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net"
container_name = "container_name"
blob_name = "<blob_name>"

download_file_path = "<file_location_to_download>"

credential = DefaultAzureCredential(additionally_allowed_tenants=["*"])
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=account_url, credential=credential)
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=blob_name)

with open(download_file_path, "wb") as download_file:
    download_file.write(blob_client.download_blob().readall())

print(f"Blob '{blob_name}' downloaded to '{download_file_path}' successfully.")

Output:


az account show tells me that "Please run 'az login' to setup account." because i have never setup using az cli. Also, tried other things but still same error

Yes, you have to sign in first using az login

@vishalpanchal, Is the issue resolved?
